# C# allowing one thread to run the method at a time after multiple requests triggerred to application server

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.NET web.api service. there is api needs more than 2 minutes to retrieve desired data, so I implemented cache mechanism, and every request sent to API Server, the server will return the cached data and meanwhile start a new thread to load new data into the cache, the issue is if I submitted a lot of requests, a lot of thread will be running and eventually crashed the server, I want to implement a mechanism to control only a thread at any certain time, but I know ASP.NET Web.API is inherently multi threads, how do I tell other request to wait, because there is one thread already retrieving new set of data ?

```
[Dependency]
    public ICacheManager<OrderArray> orderArrayCache { get; set; }
    private ReadOrderService Service = new ReadOrderService();
    private const string _ckey = "all";
    public dynamic Get()
    {
        try
        {
            OrderArray cache = orderArrayCache.Get(_ckey);
            if(cache == null || cache.orders.Length == 0)
            {
                OrderArray data = Service.GetAllOrders();
                orderArrayCache.Add(_ckey, data);
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                Caching();
                return cache;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, error.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void Caching()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() => CacheWorker());
        worker.Start();
    }
    public void CacheWorker()
    {
        try
        {
            //ActivityLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Cache Worker Is Starting to Work");
            OrderArray data = Service.GetAllOrders();
            orderArrayCache.Put(_ckey, data);
            //ActivityLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Cache Worker Is Working Hard");
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            //ActivityLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This way of implementing cache is not correct.You should have a time based expiry for cache and load new data after expiration so that subsequent requests can use the cached data. If you will wait for all the background thread to finish processing before returning result it will take the same amount of a time as retrieving new data.

Comment: You need a whole new approach. You should not spawn threads in ASP.net and you will destroy scalability by doing this. Possibly look at HangFire for updating your cache.

Comment: @Prasanjit, thanks for your commenting, but the system works in a way, it will return the cache data to the request first and then fire a new thread to refresh the data, it works, but if I make a lot of requests, the whole system crashed.

Comment: @user3425131 Try using ConcurrentBag<T> or ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> to store the cached data.

Comment: @Prasanjit I happened to read thread safe collection :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on the overall architecture, it's as trivial as setting a flag that you're working, and not starting the thread if that flag is set.

Of course in the ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI context, a controller instance is created for every request, so a simple field won't work. You could make it static, but that'll only work per AppDomain: one application can run in multiple AppDomains, by using multiple worker processes.

You could solve that by using a mutex, but then your application could be in a server farm, introducing a whole shebang of new problems.

That being said, the naive, static approach:

```
private static bool _currentlyRetrievingCacheableData = false;

public void Caching()
{
    if (_currentlyRetrievingCacheableData)
    {
        return;
    }

    Thread worker = new Thread(() => CacheWorker());
    worker.Start();
}

public void CacheWorker()
{
    try
    {
        _currentlyRetrievingCacheableData = true;

        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        _currentlyRetrievingCacheableData = false;
    }
}
```

There's still a race issue here, but at most two threads can be accessing the `CacheWorker()` method. You can prevent that by using a `lock` statement.

Do note that all of this are workarounds for doing the obvious: let the cache refreshing mechanism live outside your web application code, for example in a Windows Service or a Scheduled Task.

Comment: thanks for you comment. I have a misconception that the different request will trigger IIS to issue different thread to handle each instance of controller, so lock or ManualResetEvent will work in application server ?

Comment: Yeah this naive approach as shown won't work when the controller is instantiated for every request, of course. You'll need a named Mutex for this to work.